# 2015 Nissan Sentra CVT - Automatic Transmission Stick hard

Tags: nissan, sentra, cvt-transmission

for, 2015 Nissan Sentra shifting to park and drive sometimes is quite hard (i mean not smooth). I might need to release brake pedal, press it and try again. this time i might move but not smoothly but it works.

Is there any transmission issue? or is it like a common symptom when transmission fluid isn't changed for a long time

this is what i am facing: text copied from [Transmission service page](https://www.nshonda.com/blog/2016/november/28/why-is-it-hard-to-shift-automatic-transmission-out-of-park.htm#:%7E:text=Over%20time%2C%20grease%2C%20dirt%2C,engine%20and%20transmission%20are%20cold.)
Over time, grease, dirt, and moisture can collect in or on the interlock and brake light switches, as well as the shift cable and other related parts—hampering their operation. When this happens, you’ll have problems shifting out of Park when the engine and transmission are cold.

Once the engine warms up, the goo might become softer, making it easier to shift out of Park.

Comment: If a Nissan cvt expert doesn't comment, it might be wiser to search Nissan cvt forums for help. CVTs present problems unlike conventional geared automatics, requiring different knowledge to appreciate cvt issues.